# How to set-up a database diagram from existing tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-diagram

I have a database which has almost 300 tables, I've just come across with a problem that I've added almost 60 tables into my diagram. I can only view the entire page if I set the page zoom to %10 and it's not really useful. Anyone has any suggestions for the problem? I need to view the diagram which is able to view more useful way. If the suggestion will be one of the SQL Server 2008 built-in features I'd appreciate. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this situation I build several diagrams, each with logical subsets of tables. It is going to be easier to understand the schema with that many tables if you break it up.

On the other hand, if you are looking for the "wall of schema" and just want to make a big poster to impress people, I would use Visio to reverse engineer the schema. It provides a lot more options in terms of how the tables get layed out.

Comment: Visio suggestion is really useful.

Comment: "...and just want to make a big poster impress people". Really?  I personally think these are very helpful.  Almost like having a 3rd monitor if you're doing something that requires you to see the db diagram...

Comment: I'm with red filter on this ... trying to put 300 tables into a single ERD looks like a wiring diagram with all the cross overs. Break out the diagrams into logical groupings.

Comment: @Firat: I believe this requires the Professional edition (at least for the 2007 version).

Comment: I would suggest Erwin, Embarcadero or Sparks Enterprise Architect instead of MS Visio.

Comment: @juur: can you qualify how those options are better?

Comment: Those are real modeling tools, much more versatile compared to MS Visio. I use Sparks EA and MS Visio constantly, but prefer the former.

Comment: @juur: How are they better specifically with regards to diagram layout, which is the OP's question?

Comment: Its better, believe me, e.g. Sparks EA can reveal cardinalities much more visually and show Primary and foreign keys much more clearer that Visio.

Answer (score 2):

You can copy the whole diagram at zoom 100% and paste it as bitmap in any of your favorite image editors for further perusal. :)

Comment: I've tried it before but during the paste step an error occured, I think it was a kind of memory problem which my laptop can not handle with it.

Comment: @Firat Tuncer don't try to paste it to MS Paint, though. :) Try to use http://www.paint.net/ for example.

Answer (score 1):

create your diagrams that focus on a certain portion of your database.

create a new diagram, add only the existing tables to it for a certain area: orders, patients, etc.  don't try to have an all inclusive diagram, unless you want to view  small portions of it at one time.